# Error writing scapy RTP packet with payload type to pcap

Tags: python, scapy

When I create an RTP packet in scapy with the following code, I get an error: "TypeError: clone_with() got multiple values for keyword argument 'payload'"

```
from scapy.all import IP, UDP, RTP, Ether
from scapy.utils import PcapWriter

pktdump = PcapWriter("banana.pcap", append=False, sync=True)

rtp = { 
        "sequence": 1,
        "timestamp": 1,
        "marker": 1,
        "payload": 17
    }

pkt = Ether()/IP()/UDP(sport=12345,dport=12346)/RTP(**rtp)
pktdump.write(pkt)
```

but removing payload works.

```
rtp = { 
        "sequence": 1,
        "timestamp": 1,
        "marker": 1
    }

pkt = Ether()/IP()/UDP(sport=12345,dport=12346)/RTP(**rtp)
pktdump.write(pkt)
```

The full output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    pktdump.write(pkt)
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/utils.py", line 657, in write
    for p in pkt:
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 661, in loop
    for payl in payloads:
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 661, in loop
    for payl in payloads:
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 654, in loop
    for x in loop(todo[:], done):
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 654, in loop
    for x in loop(todo[:], done):
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 661, in loop
    for payl in payloads:
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 654, in loop
    for x in loop(todo[:], done):
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 654, in loop
    for x in loop(todo[:], done):
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 654, in loop
    for x in loop(todo[:], done):
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 654, in loop
    for x in loop(todo[:], done):
  File "/home/eisamar/devel/rtp2pcap/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 666, in loop
    pkt = self.clone_with(payload=payl, **done2)
TypeError: clone_with() got multiple values for keyword argument 'payload'
```

What am I doing wrong...? Is there a workaround? The error is on line 666... hmm...

Thanks!

Comment: Found this issue with scapy: https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/5077/rtp-packet-has-a-paylaod-field-which

Answer (score 2):

Changing the line suggested in https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/pull-requests/110/changed-rtp-field-name-from-payload-to fixes the problem by changing the name of the field from `payload` to `payload_type`.