# How to use scapy to analyze sip/rtp packet?

Tags: python, jython, sip, rtp, scapy

I am trying to write a python script using scapy(not pyshark) library to live capture the packet and extract the information. Any idea how to use scapy(jython/python) to analyze sip/rtp packet?

To make it more clearly, I had a sample code to analyse the rtp packet which use Pyshark as following:

import pyshark

import re

cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0', display_filter='sip')

for i in cap:

```
  sip= str(i[3])
  print sip
  if re.search('sendonly',sip) != None:
    print ‘yes'
```

Can this code be transferred to Scapy instead of Pyshark with the same function?

Comment: scrapy is a framework for scraping web content from web pages, what you are searching is a net inspection framework, like pyshark

Comment: Thanks, but what I am using is SCAPY not SCRAPY.

Comment: It's not clear what you need. You should strive to have a complete, minimal example of what you need assistance with. As it stands, there are multiple places that come up from a Google of "scapy rtp" and "scapy sip" that have full examples of the sort of thing you seem to be asking.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088484/error-writing-scapy-rtp-packet-with-payload-type-to-pcap being one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Kenneth,
       To start with you need some packet capture - you can do this in scapy - or using Wireshark etc. I now assume that you have a file in PCAP (or PCAPNG) format. I have also assumed that in Wireshark you are not filtering - but recording everything.

So inside Scapy you will write something like this....

```
from scapy.all import *
packets = rdpcap('filename.pcap')
```

But I can not see a **Layer** definition for SIP inside Scapy - which means you will need to develop it yourself.

Do not panic - someone has already added that for themselves. Please have a look at https://github.com/cssaheel/dissectors/blob/master/sip.py

You should be well on your way

Comment: You can use scapy `sniff` function for the capture directly in the script (see [documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf), section 8.2.1).